# Writing an array in a file in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, file

how to write an array in Ruby keeping the elements of the array itself in the same line?

E.g.

```
a= ["Tom", "Jerry"]
puts a
```

gives:

```
Tom
Jerry
```

But I need to have:

```
Tom, Jerry
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: might also want to look at the [`CSV`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class as a specific use case of writing arrays as comma separated values to a file

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `join` method on the array to do this.

```
a= ["Tom", "Jerry"]
puts a.join(", ")
```

Interestingly, you can also multiply the array by the string you wish to separate the elements by:

```
a= ["Tom", "Jerry"]
puts a * ", "
```

Both of the above give the same output:

```
Tom, Jerry
```

Comment: Wow, brilliant! Thank you so much! It works! :-)